# Can a derived class specialize its parent's template member function?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I intend to implement a nested number type. Simply speaking, I want to create a class/type to adapt a nested list such as `[1, [2, 3], [[4, 5], 6, [7, [8]]]]` . I also want to implement a `get` function to access the element. Ideally, in the above example `get<int>` should access a single number while `get<std::vector<NestedNum>>` should be able to retrieve the list.

Here is a sketch:

```
template <typename T>
class NestedNumItem {
  public:
    NestedNumItem() {}
    NestedNumItem(T v): val(v) {}

    template <typename S>
    S get() { return val; }

  private:
    T val;
};

template <typename T>
class NestedNum: public NestedNumItem<T> {
  public:
    NestedNum() {}
    NestedNum(T v): NestedNumItem<T>(v) {}

    // quote the template function defined in the base class
    using NestedNumItem<T>::get;

    // Error: no function template matches function template specialization 'get'
    template <>
    std::vector<NestedNum> get() { return vec; }

    void push_back(NestedNum &num) { vec.push_back(num); }

    NestedNum& operator[] (size_t i) { return vec[i]; }

  private:
    std::vector<NestedNum> vec;
};
```

However, it seems that the derived class is not able to "see" its parent's template member function. Is there anyway to solve this? Thanks for helping out!

EDIT:

After several attempts, here is a better version with fancier templates.

```
template <typename T, template<typename, typename...> class Container, typename... Rest>
class Nested {
  public:
    Nested() { data = Container<Rest..., Nested>(); }
    Nested(T a) { data = a; }

    // Nested-conatiner type
    using NestedCon = Container<Rest..., Nested>;

    // Nested-container-reference
    using NestedConRef = Container<Rest..., Nested>&;

    // template of get() function
    template <typename S>
    S get();

    template<>
    T get() { return std::get<T>(data); }

    template<>
    NestedConRef get() { return std::get<NestedCon>(data); }

  private:
    std::variant<T, Container<Rest..., Nested>> data;
};
```

With the aid of `template template parameter` now we are able to assign desired container for different purposes. Here are two exampes/tests:

```
TEST(TestNested, test_init_vec) {
  using NestedInt = Nested<int, std::vector>;
  NestedInt nv;
  NestedInt a(100);
  nv.get<NestedInt::NestedConRef>().push_back(a);

  cout << nv.get<NestedInt::NestedConRef>()[0].get<int>() << "\n";
}

TEST(TestNested, test_init_umap) {
  using NestedUmap = Nested<int, std::unordered_map, std::string>;
  NestedUmap num;
  NestedUmap a(101);
  num.get<NestedUmap::NestedConRef>()["ab"] = a;

  cout << num.get<NestedUmap::NestedConRef>()["ab"].get<int>() << "\n";
}
```

The outputs are as expected:

```
100
101
```

REMARK:

It's possible to simplify the get-assign syntax even further, but for the demo purpose, I'll leave it as it is:)

Comment: Your class should contain a `std::variant<T, std::vector<MyClass<T>>>`. I don't see how inheritance could help here.

Comment: So you want the same object to be both a single number and a list of numbers?

Comment: You're right. The sketch is about making a class adapting a single number and a list of numbers, but that's not the main purpose. What I really want is to learn how template works in inheritance:)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your design. For example: `NestedNumItem`'s template parameter `T` should always be equal(or converted) to `S`(because `get` returns `var`); `NestedNum` has a fixed member variable with type `std::vector<NestedNum>`...

But, if just talk about your question in title, the short answer is "NO". And the reason is a little complex.

First, let's look at this line: `using NestedNumItem<T>::get;` This will not introduce a template name into `NestedNum` because `get` is a [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name). You must write `using NestedNumItem<T>::template get;` to tell compiler `get` is a template.

Second, even if you write `using NestedNumItem<T>::template get;`, it is still illegal because [C++ doesn't allow using-declaration to introduce the name of a dependent member template as a template-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

```
template<class X>
struct B
{
    template<class T>
    void f(T);
};
 
template<class Y>
struct D : B<Y>
{
//  using B<Y>::template f; // Error: disambiguator not allowed
    using B<Y>::f;          // compiles, but f is not a template-name
 
    void g()
    {
//      f<int>(0);          // Error: f is not known to be a template name,
                            // so < does not start a template argument list
        f(0);               // OK
    }   
};
```

(The above example is taken from cppreference)

Actually, if you really want derived class to override some behavior that exists in base class, you can just define a new member function in derived class. There's no need for specialization here:

```
template <typename T>
class NestedNum: public NestedNumItem<T> {
  public:
    // omitted code...

    // define get in derived class
    vector<NestedNum<T>> get() { return {}; }
}
```

But, as said earlier, you should check your design first. This may not be a suitable solution for you specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your message! My primary objective with this sketch is to learn how templates work in inheritance. Initially, I thought it will be nice if we can specialize a parent's template member function. It's ok if the mechanism doesn't work in that way. I'll use a different design to work around.